# How do I write a Dax statement that returns the current counts whenever I filter for a TEam

Tags: powerbi, dax

Below is my sample table and I'd like to write a Dax statement that returns the current count
whenever I filter for Team A or B. Ideally, the current count per team would be on a card in power BI.

| team | yearmonth | active_cnt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2023-06 | 10 |
| a | 2023-07 | 15 |
| a | 2023-08 | 30 |
| b | 2023-06 | 15 |
| b | 2023-07 | 25 |
| b | 2023-08 | 30 |

Below was my attempt but it returned a blank response:

```
CurrentCountPerTeam = 
SUMX(
FILTER(
    'Query1',
    'Query1'[yearmonth] = YEAR(TODAY()) * 100 + MONTH(TODAY())
),
'Query1'[active_cnt]
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a variable that stores the current year & month and then compare to the yearmonth column to pull the current year & month count for each Team

```
  CurrentCountPerTeam =
  VAR __CurrentYearMonth = DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY()), 1)
  RETURN
  SUMX(
  FILTER(
  'Query1',
  'Query1'[yearmonth] = __CurrentYearMonth
   ),
  'Query1'[active_cnt]
   )
```